# Minecraft java edition 1.14.4 chunk lag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been experiencing a lag while moving from one chunk to another at certain places in the world. I noticed it at a couple of places near my initial spawn point. This is in Single player mode

Few notable things:

1. Cobblestone walls seem to be a a factor. Both the places had cobblestone walls and on rearranging the wall layout at one of the places, the issue got resolved. On the other location, it isn't feasible for me to remove the wall, so I haven't been able to test it.
2. It is a persistent issue. It has been logged in many places by different players and seems to happen often. But, I didn't experience it earlier (at those locations) so I am hoping someone has insight into what can be done to get around it.

Comment: Is it just a quick lag spike? If you press Alt+F3, is there just one big red line and the rest is lower and green? Then it might be https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-123584. Does it happen again if you break or place a block very near those cobblestone walls?

Comment: I do get a spike sometimes. But this isn't related to building or breaking of blocks. The lag happens when I pass certain chunk boundaries.

Comment: Then I don't know what causes it. Blame 1.14, I guess. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Maybe you could look at Shift+F3 and see what the biggest portion is, but that's hard for single lag spikes.